# What is the value of the integral $ \int _{-3}^{3} u(x-2) \delta(x-3)dx $

Tags: integration

What is the value of the integral $ \int _{-3}^{3} u(x-2) \delta(x-3)dx  $

Observation:
$u(x)$ is the unit step function. $ \delta(x)$ is the impulse function. The problem lies in the fact that the integral is evaluated from -3 to 3 and at the same time the impulse is located at 3. I am not able to understand how to evaluate this integral.

Comment: It's too ill-defined for even the most adventurous of physicists. Deltas should never be at the endpoints of intervals.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

I is not hard to prove that:

$$\int\limits_{-\text{n}}^\text{n}\theta\left(x-\text{n}+1\right)\delta\left(x-\text{n}\right)\space\text{d}x=2\theta\left(\text{n}\right)-1\tag1$$

When $\text{n}\in\mathbb{R}$.